# Loop through, return true if a function passes

Tags: prolog

```
classify(N, X) :- N > 100, X = 'big'.
classify(N, X) :- N > 50, N < 100, X = 'medium'.
classify(N, X) :- N < 50, X = 'small'.

contains_big([]) :- fail.
contains_big([H|T]) :- classify(H, 'big'), contains_big(T), !.
contains_big([H|T]) :- \+ classify(H, 'big'), contains_big(T).
```

This is my current code. I am trying to recursively loop through a list, and return true if classify passes, else return false.
How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

In Prolog, you only need to declare what is true (what cannot be proven to be true is assumed to be false).

A list `[X|Xs]` contains a big element if:

- the first element `X`in the list is a big element, or
- one of the other elements in the list `Xs` is a big element.

Moreover, you also need classify numbers 50 and 100 as, for example, medium elements.

That is:

```
contains_big([X|_]) :- classify(X, big).
contains_big([_|Xs]) :- contains_big(Xs).

classify(N, small ) :- N < 50.
classify(N, medium) :- N >= 50, N =< 100.
classify(N, big   ) :- N > 100.
```

Examples:

```
?- maplist(classify, [900, 70, 20, 10], Cs).
Cs = [big, medium, small, small] .

?- contains_big([900, 70, 20, 10]).
true .

?- maplist(classify, [90, 70, 200, 100], Cs).
Cs = [medium, medium, big, medium] .

?- contains_big([90, 70, 200, 100]).
true .

?- maplist(classify, [90, 70, 20, 100], Cs).
Cs = [medium, medium, small, medium] .

?- contains_big([90, 70, 20, 100]).
false.
```